# Layer rendering using geometry shader seems to only output the first layer of an image array

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm trying to do some layered rendering on an image array, and display one of the layer on the screen. 
But no matter what I do, only the first layer is rendered and displayed correctly, each time I try to display another layer than the first, I get nothing than a black screen.
So I tried to pack most of the necessary informations, hoping for someone to find my mistake.

So first, I have created an image with thoses parameters :

```
VkImageCreateInfo info{};
info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_CREATE_INFO;
info.imageType = VK_IMAGE_TYPE_2D;
info.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
info.extent = { WindowWidth, WindowHeight, 1 };
info.mipLevels = 1;
info.arrayLayers = 6;
info.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
info.tiling = VK_IMAGE_TILING_OPTIMAL;
info.usage = VK_IMAGE_USAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_BIT | VK_IMAGE_USAGE_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_BIT;
info.sharingMode = VK_SHARING_MODE_EXCLUSIVE;
info.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;

VkImage myImage = createImage(info);
```

I omited the whole memory allocation and binding gymnastic because I think it's not relevant here.

Then, I used two image views : 
- One with the whole {0, 6} layer range, which is going to be used for layer rendering in geometry shader
- The other with only one layer which is going to be used to fetch the datas at the given layer of my choice

Here is how I created them :

```
VkImageViewCreateInfo info{};
info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_VIEW_CREATE_INFO;
info.image = myImage;
info.viewType = VK_IMAGE_VIEW_TYPE_2D;
info.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
info.components = Identity;
info.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
info.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
info.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;
info.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
info.subresourceRange.layerCount = 6;

VkImageView imageView6Layers = createImageView(info);

VkImageViewCreateInfo info2 = info; 
info2.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 1; // Target the layer 1 for example
info2.subresourceRange.layerCount = 1;

VkImageView imageView1Layer = createImageView(info2);
```

At this point, I have built two render passes to divide the process :

- The first render all the image layers in one draw call with a geometry shader, using the first image view
- The second fetch the datas from the second image view, and output them to the swapchain image

Here is the first render pass (for layered rendering) :

```
// 6 layers image view
VkAttachmentDescription attachment{};  
attachment.format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
attachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
attachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
attachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachment.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
attachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference colorAttachment{};
colorAttachment.attachment = 0;
colorAttachment.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkSubpassDescription subpass{};
subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachment;

VkRenderPassCreateInfo info{};
info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
info.attachmentCount = 1;
info.pAttachments = &attachment;
info.subpassCount = 1;
info.pSubpasses = &subpass;

VkRenderPass renderPass6Layers = createRenderPass(info);
```

Here is the second render pass (fetching datas, and output it to the swapchain image) :

```
VkAttachmentDescription attachments[2]{};

// Swapchain image
attachments[0].format = swpachainImageFormat;
attachments[0].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachments[0].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
attachments[0].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
attachments[0].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[0].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[0].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
attachments[0].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

// 1 layer image view
attachments[1].format = VK_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
attachments[1].samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachments[1].loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_LOAD;
attachments[1].storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[1].stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[1].stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments[1].initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
attachments[1].finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference colorAttachment{};
colorAttachment.attachment = 0;
colorAttachment.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkAttachmentReference inputAttachment{};
inputAttachment.attachment = 1;
inputAttachment.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;

VkSubpassDescription subpass{};
subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachment;
subpass.inputAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pInputAttachments = &inputAttachment;

VkRenderPassCreateInfo info{};
info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
info.attachmentCount = 2;
info.pAttachments = attachments;
info.subpassCount = 1;
info.pSubpasses = &subpass;

VkRenderPass renderPass1Layer = createRenderPass(info);
```

Then the shaders used in the first subpass :

Vertex shader :

```
#version 450

layout (location = 0) in vec3 iModelPos;

void main() 
{   
    gl_Position = vec4(iModelPos, 1);
}
```

Geometry shader :

```
#version 450

layout (triangles) in;
layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < gl_in.length(); j++)
        {
            gl_Layer = i;

            // Assume I have everything necessary to compute the matrix
            gl_Position = PVM * gl_in[j].gl_Position;

            EmitVertex();
        }

        EndPrimitive();
    }
}
```

Fragment shader :

```
#version 450

layout (location = 0) out vec4 oColor;

void main() 
{
    oColor = vec4(1,1,1,1);
}
```

The shaders used in the second subpass :

Vertex shader (simply ouput a quad on the whole screen) :

```
#version 450

layout (location = 0) in vec3 iModelPos;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = vec4(iModelPos, 1);
}
```

Fragment shader (fetching data in the image layer) :

```
#version 450

// Assume it's bound here
layout (input_attachment_index = 0, set = 0, binding = 0) uniform subpassInput ImageLayer;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 oColor;

void main() 
{
    oColor = subpassLoad(ImageLayer);
}
```

And finally what my main looks like :

```
int main(void)
{
    /* ... */

    {
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo info{};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
        info.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;

        vkBeginCommandBuffer(cmdBuffer, &info);
    }

    VkFramebuffer framebuffer6Layers{}
    {
        VkFramebufferCreateInfo info{};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
        info.renderPass = renderPass6Layers;
        info.attachmentCount = 1;
        info.pAttachments = &imageView6Layers;
        info.width = WindowWidth;
        info.height = WindowHeight;
        info.layers = 6;

        framebuffer6Layers = createFramebuffer(info);
    }

    {
        VkClearValue clearValues = {0,0,0,1};

        VkRenderPassBeginInfo info{};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
        info.renderPass = renderPass6Layers;
        info.framebuffer = framebuffer6Layers;
        info.renderArea = { WindowWidth, WindowHeight };
        info.clearValueCount = 1;
        info.pClearValues = &clearValues;

        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cmdBuffer, &info, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
    }

    /* binds */

    vkCmdDraw(cmdBuffer, objectVertices.count(), 1, 0, 0);

    vkCmdEndRenderPass(cmdBuffer);
    vkEndCommandBuffer(cmdBuffer);

    /* submit cmdBuffer and wait for rendering to finish */

    {
        VkCommandBufferBeginInfo info{};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER_BEGIN_INFO;
        info.flags = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_USAGE_ONE_TIME_SUBMIT_BIT;

        vkBeginCommandBuffer(cmdBuffer, &info);
    }

    {
        VkImageMemoryBarrier barrier{};
        barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_IMAGE_MEMORY_BARRIER;
        barrier.image = myImage;
        barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT;
        barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_INPUT_ATTACHMENT_READ_BIT;
        barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
        barrier.oldLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.newLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_SHADER_READ_ONLY_OPTIMAL;
        barrier.subresourceRange.aspectMask = VK_IMAGE_ASPECT_COLOR_BIT;
        barrier.subresourceRange.baseArrayLayer = 0;
        barrier.subresourceRange.layerCount = 6;
        barrier.subresourceRange.baseMipLevel = 0;
        barrier.subresourceRange.levelCount = 1;

        vkCmdPipelineBarrier(cmdBuffer, 
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, 
        VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_FRAGMENT_SHADER_BIT, 
        0, 
        0, nullptr, 
        0, nullptr, 
        1, &barrier);
    }

    VkFramebuffer framebuffer1Layer{};
    {
        VkImageView attachments[2]{};
        attachments[0] = swapchainImageView;
        attachments[1] = imageView1Layer;

        VkFramebufferCreateInfo info{};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_FRAMEBUFFER_CREATE_INFO;
        info.renderPass = renderPass1Layer;
        info.attachmentCount = 2;
        info.pAttachments = attachments;
        info.width = WindowWidth;
        info.height = WindowHeight;
        info.layers = 1;

        framebuffer1Layer = createFramebuffer(info);
    }

    {
        VkClearValue clearValues = {0,0,0,1};

        VkRenderPassBeginInfo info{};
        info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
        info.renderPass = renderPass1Layer;
        info.framebuffer = framebuffer1Layer;
        info.renderArea = { WindowWidth, WindowHeight };
        info.clearValueCount = 1;
        info.pClearValues = &clearValues;

        vkCmdBeginRenderPass(cmdBuffer, &info, VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE);
    }

    /* binds */

    vkCmdDraw(quadVertices.count(), 1, 0, 0);

    vkCmdEndRenderPass(cmdBuffer);
    vkEndCommandBuffer(cmdBuffer);

    /* submit cmdBuffer, wait for rendering to finish and present the swapchain image */

    /* ... */
}
```

I didn't include some informations, like framebuffer creation.
I feel like I have already given many informations, and I hope someone will figure out what's going wrong, or give some hints.

### EDIT 1 :

The validation layers are working, and do not output anything.

### EDIT 2 :

I found that I was actually always creating my framebuffer with only one layer for some reasons, which explain why the validation layers never complained.

To use the correct number of layer in the framebuffer, I have split the process in two render passes, and added an image barrier in between (see the process edited above). 
However it didn't solve the problem, I still have a black screen when trying to display another image layer than the first, and correct results when displaying the first layer.

The validation layers do not complain now either, and I added the framebuffer creation details as requested.

### EDIT 3 :

I tried to use a combined image sampler uniform instead of the input attachment, with no luck. It still works when I try to display the first layer, but I get the same black screen from the others.

I removed the attachment from the second render pass and updated the memory barrier in consequence.

Here is the update of the second render pass :

```
// Swapchain image
VkAttachmentDescription attachment{};
attachment.format = swpachainImageFormat;
attachment.samples = VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT;
attachment.loadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR;
attachment.storeOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE;
attachment.stencilLoadOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachment.stencilStoreOp = VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE;
attachments.initialLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED;
attachment.finalLayout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR;

VkAttachmentReference colorAttachment{};
colorAttachment.attachment = 0;
colorAttachment.layout = VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OPTIMAL;

VkSubpassDescription subpass{};
subpass.pipelineBindPoint = VK_PIPELINE_BIND_POINT_GRAPHICS;
subpass.colorAttachmentCount = 1;
subpass.pColorAttachments = &colorAttachment;

VkRenderPassCreateInfo info{};
info.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_RENDER_PASS_BEGIN_INFO;
info.attachmentCount = 1;
info.pAttachments = &attachment;
info.subpassCount = 1;
info.pSubpasses = &subpass;

VkRenderPass renderPass1Layer = createRenderPass(info);
```

Here is the new fragment shader :

```
// Assume it's bound here
layout (set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D ImageLayer;

layout (location = 0) out vec4 oColor;

void main() 
{
    // Assume that I have the viewport from an uniform buffer.
    const vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / Viewport;
    oColor = texture(ImageLayer, uv);
}
```

The uv value is correct, when I try to output vec4(uv, 0, 1) I get the expected colors on the screen, for every image layers I try to display :

black, red,

green, yellow

And here is the change on the image barrier :

```
barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_UNIFORM_READ_BIT;
```

There is also some changes on for example image usage flags, or descriptor set layout but I did not include them here.

Comment: What do your validation layers tell you?

Comment: Please add your framebuffer setup code. It's relevant too, esp. the attachment setup part, as these also have have a ```layerCount```.

Comment: @NicolBolas Nothing.

Comment: @SaschaWillems See my edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally figured out what was going wrong.

> layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 3) out;

This line in my geometry shader caused the other vertices after the third vertex being 
**silently** discarded. Thus, the only layer on which my shader was able to write was the first one.

I've fixed the problem like this :

`layout (triangle_strip, max_vertices = 18) out;`

I want to draw a triangle (3 vertices) on 6 layers, hence max_vertices = 3 x 6 = 18.

The other problem was solved in my edit 3. My framebuffers were created with only 1 layer instead of the 6 needed, making the geometry shader **silently** writing on the first layer exclusively. It seems that when you try to write on a layer greater than the number of layer you provided in the framebuffer, the shader automagically write on the layer 0.